# How to use localized messages on velocity templates on Spring Boot applications?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, velocity

How to use localized messages read from resource files like `messages_en.properties` on Velocity templates on Spring Boot application?

On JSP files, we can use:

```
<spring:message code="label.description"/>
```

What is the equivalent for .vm files? If possible, please let me know.

Comment: The reference guide answers that question. See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#views-form-macros .

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Deinum: on the reference documentation:

For Velocity:

message (output a string from a resource bundle based on the code parameter)

```
#springMessage($code)
```